# Certificates not work on IOS when using react-native-ssl-pinning

Tags: react-native, ssl-certificate

I drag mycert.cer to Xcode project, mark my target and 'Copy items if needed'
and I use this code, but it does not work:

import {fetch} from 'react-native-ssl-pinning';

```
fetch('****.com', {
    method: "GET" ,
    timeoutInterval: communication_timeout, // milliseconds
    body: {},
    sslPinning: {
        certs: ["mycert"]
    },
    headers: {
        Accept: "application/json; charset=utf-8", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*", "e_platform": "mobile",
    }
})
.then(response => {
    console.log(`response received ${response}`)
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log(`error: ${err}`)
})
```

It threw error that:  `URL unsupport` or `The certificate for this server is not valid. You may be connecting to a server posing as “****.com”, which could jeopardize your security information.`

Can anyone help me?
Thanks in Advance

I expect that I can use certificates ssl pinning in react-native(run on android and IOS)